# Dedicated LPG Ute, long distance drive, VIC to QLD

Tags: driving, australia, gas-stations

Need to drive to Ipswich QLD from Ballarat VIC, have a dedicated LPG vehicle, anyone know which route would be the best to take for enough Petrol Stations that sell LPG?

Is there an app or website with a map of LPG petrol stations?

I cannot seem to find what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This website claims to offer a full listing of 2403 LPG stations in Australia, including confirmations from station owners and recent users:

https://www.mylpg.eu/stations/australia/#map

https://www.mylpg.eu/stations/australia/list/

LPG cars are definitely a dying breed, so I'd still be cautious, but even so you should have no problems at all if you take the Pacific Highway to Sydney and continue to Melbourne on the Hume.  The most direct route via Newell Highway looks more dicey, in particular there's a 500 km stretch from Goondiwindi to Dubbo with no LPG stations listed.

Comment: Awesome, will check it out, appreciate your help. I'm actually going to QLD from VIC, but still the same rout.